# Does formatting an SSD shorten its lifespan?

Tags: ssd, formatting

I would like to perform a format on my SSD. I've read several files on shortening the SSD's lifespan, but never read anything about formatting.

Does formatting an SSD shorten its lifespan?

Comment: Related: [Secure format of an SSD](http://superuser.com/questions/101465/secure-format-of-an-ssd)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, formatting a solid-state drive will **not** impact its lifetime, *unless* you perform a full format - and even then, it depends how often.  Most formatting utilities allow you to do a quick or full format.  The quick format just overwrites the partition and file tables, but does not actually physically delete anything off of the disk.

In contrast, a full format will go through each sector on a disk and "reset" it.  This can degrade the lifetime of the SSD.  That being said, MLC solid state drives have a write limit of around 10,000 before the sectors begin to fail.

So long as you don't do it often, (fully) formatting the drive a few times won't seriously impact on the drive lifespan.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting = writing.

Modern SSDs have a command for clearing all data, *ATA Secure Erase*. Take a look in the software provided by your SSD manufacturer.