# How to overwrite deleted files completely the right way

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, secure-erase

I have 1 TB hard drive, and I want to delete sensitive data from it.
What I have tried:

- Format the hard-drive "deep slow format" from CMD command.
- I tried c-tools.
- Also I tried cipher built in tool that came with windows 10.

But nothing worked.
I also used cipher tool 3 times to be sure it write random numbers on my deleted files but that doesn't work.

With normal recovery tool I can backup the same data again!

Is there any good command to rewrite on these deleted files so no one can recover them again?

Comment: The solution is usually *"don't write sensitive information to storage unencrypted"*. It sounds like the software you are using is broke, but we would need more details. Trying to wipe the drive after the fact is like trying to put out the fire after the house burned down. Also see [Reliably Erasing Data From Flash-Based Solid State Drives](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/fast11/tech/full_papers/Wei.pdf) by Wei, Grupp, Spada, and Swanson.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I securely format a solid-state drive?](https://superuser.com/q/101465/173513), [How can I securely wipe an SSD?](https://superuser.com/q/1102184/173513), and friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your tools (except format),
but evidently something you are doing is not going right.

There are many free disk-shredding utilities.
You may find a list with reviews in the article
[Best Free Hard Drive Eraser](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-hard-drive-eraser.htm),
which includes Eraser, CCleaner, Darik's Boot and Nuke, File Shredder, and more.

Answer (score 0):

If preservation of the drive is not important, perhaps physical destruction of the device is your best option. A sledgehammer ought to do the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure a slegdehammer counts as a command

Comment: @bertieb User's objective is to make a set of files stored on a hard drive irrecoverable. User's proposed solution is to securely erase files using software. User has difficulty doing so using such software methods. Some of the examples given are known while others seem vague. While I could give yet another software answer, a very good one has already been given. Physical destruction is simple, universally understandable, and a viable alternative, especially if asker's technical depth is uncertain.

Comment: If physical destruction was listed as an addendum / post-script to other suggestions I would not have commented. However, OP asked for a command to overwrite / rewrite them. In any case, you should explain the choice of a sledgehammer, what exactly needs destroyed in the drive and *why* you are recommending this course of action- if you're to go off the beaten track, explain why :) Also, the other answer links to a list of software and doesn't explain *how* to securely format/overwrite/delete, which is what OP is missing...

Comment: @bertieb I see no reason destroying the drive has to be listed as an "addendum / post-script". If certain conditions are met, namely, if he doesn't care for the drive, then this is a perfectly valid alternative. I make this clear from the very beginning. It sounds like you have a lot of ideas regarding how to improve others' answers. Perhaps you can write your own, better one.