# Can deleting all files then filling the SSD totally with other files securely wipe old data?

Tags: ssd, secure-erase

We all know about how SSD is bad when one wants to securely delete specific files (not the whole disk).

Did anyone test if this securely overwrites all files (performed from within the OS):

1. delete all files from SSD by deleting all files on it
2. copy some image (or other files) and then copy/paste it until disk is full

Will this new file overwrite the cells where old data was stored?

If not, why this method does not work?

PS. if this method works, does it mean that Linux command `dd with if/of` works as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I securely wipe an SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/1102184/how-can-i-securely-wipe-an-ssd)

Comment: The top answer to the duplicate tells why its a no.